# adding a block corresponding a downloaded module

Tags: drupal

I have just downloaded and installed the 'facebook status' module and 'user feedback' module both of which provide a block for display as follows:
1)facebook status module provides a block for display of facebook status messages
2)user feedback module provides a block for feedback (of the site) from users.

But when I listed the 'Blocks' under the 'Site Building' Tab I was not able to see the block corresponding to any one of the two, not even in the 'disabled blocks' section.

Is there some way to access these blocks. I don't think there is a bug in both of thses modules as I have seen others use it(but not how). Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module was installed but it was not working properly due to lack of space available in the database. I uninstalled some less important modules, which cleared some space of the mysql database and got it working again.